# Android: starting activity with extra bitmap error

Tags: android, bitmap

I have created app, that allows me upload picture on web. I resize it via PHP, and then I'm trying to load these pictures into another app...

**I have this code for download image:**

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
                try {
                    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    return myBitmap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
}
```

**Then I have AsyncTask, where I download all images:**
(I'm trying to organize picture to be two in row)

```
public class loadPhotos extends AsyncTask<String,Object,Void>{
            ProgressBar pb;

            ImageView img;
            TableRow.LayoutParams paramsImage;

            List<String> urlsOfImages; //gained from database
            TableLayout tl;
            TableRow tr;
            LayoutParams lp;

            int numberOfPhotos=0;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                urlsOfImages = new ArrayList<String>();
                allUserPhotoBitmaps.clear(); // saved bitmaps

                pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.profile_photos_progress_bar);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_photos_table_layout);
                tl.removeAllViews(); //clear all photos before load new one

                tr = new TableRow(Profile.this);
                lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
                allUserPhotoInformations = myDb.getUrlsOfUserImages(arg[0],arg[1],arg[2]); //This returns List<HashMap<String,String>> , where I'm storing information from web database like : URL, Country, City, Latitude, Longitude etc...

                Log.w("AllUserPhotoInformations","SIZE: "+ allUserPhotoInformations.size()); //Testing if size is OK

                for (int i=0 ; i < allUserPhotoInformations.size() ; i++){
                    Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL(allUserPhotoInformations.get(i).get("file_path")); //getting bitmap from function posted above
                    allUserPhotoBitmaps.add(bm); //saving bitmap to List<Bitmap>
                    publishProgress(bm,i); // Publishing progress with Object bitmap and index
                }

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... arg){

                img = new ImageView(Profile.this);
                paramsImage = new TableRow.LayoutParams(((int)(screenWidth/2))-30, ((int)(screenWidth/2))-30);
                paramsImage.setMargins(10,10,0,0);

                img.setLayoutParams(paramsImage);
                img.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) arg[0]);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                img.setOnClickListener(new ImageListener((Integer)arg[1])); //here I'm passing the index to onClick listener.

                tr.addView(img);

                if ( numberOfPhotos==1 ){
                    // If there's already two photos in tableRow, add the TableRow into TableLayout with these two pictures
                    try{
                        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // And create new tableRow
                    tr = new TableRow(Profile.this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    numberOfPhotos--;
                }
                else {
                    numberOfPhotos++;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void arg){
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                userPhotos.setText("uploaded: "+allUserPhotoBitmaps.size()+" photos");

                if ( numberOfPhotos==1 ){
                    //If there was odd number of pictures, add the last into tableLayout too
                    try{
                        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    /* Vytvor novej radek */
                    tr = new TableRow(Profile.this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            }
}
```

And here sometimes it show all of pictures and sometimes loads two of them , then the Application restarts, and sometimes it restarts immediately...

At last... There's the OnClick method:

```
public class ImageListener implements OnClickListener{
                int index;
                Bitmap bm;
                byte[] byteArray;

                public ImageListener(int index) {
                    this.index = index;

                    try {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        allUserPhotoBitmaps.get(index).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
                        byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

//All log bellow contains no error

                    Log.w("bitmap",""+byteArray);
                    Log.w("country",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("country"));
                    Log.w("city",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("city"));
                    Log.w("latitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("latitude"));
                    Log.w("longitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("longitude"));
                    Log.w("description",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("description"));
                    Log.w("category",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("category"));
                    Log.w("date",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("date"));

                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    try {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowPhotoDetails.class);

                        Log.w("onCLICK","1"); //ok

                        i.putExtra("bitmap",byteArray);

                        Log.w("onCLICK","2"); //ok

                        i.putExtra("country",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("country"));
                        i.putExtra("city",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("city"));
                        i.putExtra("latitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("latitude"));
                        i.putExtra("longitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("longitude"));
                        i.putExtra("description",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("description"));
                        i.putExtra("category",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("category"));
                        i.putExtra("date",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("date"));

                        Log.w("onCLICK","3"); // ok

                        startActivity(i);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Error showing image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
```

My problem is, that when all pictures is shown properly (in one of the cases) and I clicked on first, there's no problem at all... But when I try to open for example last one... All logs ( "onCLICK","1" ; "onClick", "2" ; "onClick" , "3" ) will be visible, but apps restarts after that...

And then there's ShowPhotoDetails.class wich have the intentExtras in it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_photo_details);

    Log.w("SHOW_PHOTO_DETAILS","CREATED"); // Not OK
}
```

and YES ! I have declared all activities in Manifest and I have all permissions too...

Comment: And what print logcat? No errors? AND! ImageClickListener is a inner class of your Activity?

Comment: Logcat gives no error, ImageClickLister is a inner class of AsyncTask ... is that a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShowPhotoDetails.class);

                    Log.w("onCLICK","1"); //ok

                    i.putExtra("bitmap",byteArray);

                    Log.w("onCLICK","2"); //ok

                    i.putExtra("country",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("country"));
                    i.putExtra("city",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("city"));
                    i.putExtra("latitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("latitude"));
                    i.putExtra("longitude",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("longitude"));
                    i.putExtra("description",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("description"));
                    i.putExtra("category",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("category"));
                    i.putExtra("date",allUserPhotoInformations.get(index).get("date"));

                    Log.w("onCLICK","3"); // ok

                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Error showing image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

change **getApplicationContext()** to **getBaseContext()**

Comment: Tried... no change... But I realized, it always restarts when theres a "bigger" image... all images have max of 500kb, but in resolution it's clearly bigger than other. Could it be in this ?

Comment: Your Activity not started?

Comment: Maybe I have found the problem... It's like when server do not respond extra well (You know, higher ping than usual) Application restarts... But If I have good signal on Wi-Fi, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!! It was because of resolution of image...

```
width = (screenWidth)/myBitmap.getRowBytes();
if ( myBitmap.getWidth() > myBitmap.getHeight() ){
    height = ((myBitmap.getRowBytes()*width)/16)*11;
    width = (height/11)*16;
}
else {
    height = ((myBitmap.getRowBytes()*width)/11)*16;
    width = (height/16)*10;
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, (int)width, (int)height, true);
```